# Psycopg2 : Insert multiple values if not exists in the table

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I need to insert multiple values into a table after checking if it doesn't exist using psycopg2.
The query am using:

```
WITH data(name,proj_id) as (
    VALUES ('hello',123),('hey',123)
)
INSERT INTO keywords(name,proj_id)
SELECT d.name,d.proj_id FROM data d 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM keywords u2 WHERE
u2.name=d.name AND u2.proj_id=d.proj_id)
```

But how to format or add the values section from tuple to **('hello',123),('hey',123)** in query.

Comment: It would be cheaper to use [`on conflict do nothing`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT) instead of `where not exists`.

Comment: can we use on conflict on non unique column?

Comment: No, it requires a constraint. I assumed that's your motive, lacking your DDL for the `keywords` table. Since I don't know your PostgreSQL version either, I'll also go ahead and suggest PostgreSQL15+ [`MERGE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-merge.html), which doesn't require a constraint. Not leaving your question unaddressed: there's [more than one way](https://hakibenita.com/fast-load-data-python-postgresql#insert-rows-one-by-one), depending on how fast you want to go.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
insert_query = """WITH data(name, proj_id) as (
                  VALUES (%s,%s)
                  ) 
                INSERT INTO keywords(name, proj_id) 
                SELECT d.name,d.proj_id FROM data d 
                WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                  SELECT 1 FROM keywords u2 
                  WHERE u2.name = d.name AND u2.proj_id = d.proj_id)"""
tuple_values = (('hello',123),('hey',123))
            
psycopg2.extras.execute_batch(cursor,insert_query,tuple_values)
```

Here I created a tuple which holds the data to be inserted. Then execute_batch() method of the psycopg2.extras module is used to execute the insert_query with the tuple_values as the parameter. The execute_batch() method can be used to efficiently execute a parameterized query multiple times with different sets of parameters, which makes it useful for bulk inserts.

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation to the source code explaining how it solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As [suggested](https://hakibenita.com/fast-load-data-python-postgresql#insert-rows-one-by-one) in the comment, assuming that your connection is already established as `conn` one of the ways would be:

```python
from typing import Iterator, Dict, Any

def insert_execute_values_iterator(connection, keywords: Iterator[Dict[str, Any]], page_size: int = 1000) -> None:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        psycopg2.extras.execute_values(
           cursor,
           """  WITH data(name,proj_id) as (VALUES %s)
                INSERT INTO keywords(name,proj_id)
                SELECT d.name,d.proj_id FROM data d 
                WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM keywords u2 WHERE
                u2.name=d.name AND u2.proj_id=d.proj_id);""", 
           (( keyword['name'],
              keyword['proj_id'] ) for keyword in keywords),
           page_size=page_size)


insert_execute_values_iterator(conn,{'hello':123,'hey':123})
```

Comment: What about this execute_batch?: 

`"""WITH data(name,proj_id) as (
VALUES (%s,%s))
INSERT INTO keywords(name,proj_id)
SELECT d.name,d.proj_id FROM data d 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM keywords u2 WHERE u2.name=d.name AND u2.proj_id=d.proj_id)"""`

`psycopg2.extras.execute_batch(cursor,insert_query,tuple_values)`

Comment: @BibinHashleyOP Looking just as fine. No need to spend too much time on tweaking an insert mechanism if you don't insert too much, too often. :) I also found that I might need to go back on my initial comment regarding your query: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/PUQhpY9T). This test shows that on a million rows, `on conflict` is much slower and `merge` the same at best. One difference is I don't think they would let you insert duplicates within an incoming batch, while `where not exists` will - it checks the incoming vs already present, but doesn't check all incoming records against each other.

Comment: Correction for my [correction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74450641/psycopg2-insert-multiple-values-if-not-exists-in-the-table#comment131430203_74451088) of my [correction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74450641/psycopg2-insert-multiple-values-if-not-exists-in-the-table#comment131428368_74450641): constraint with `on conflict do nothing` won't allow duplicates, ever, but will be the slowest. `Merge` will act the same as your `where not exists`, allowing duplicates within new batch. As the quickest, `where not exists` approach wins, you win. [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/C8kLeVtT)